# Bot on Facebook Channel: getting empty string instead of email

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, botframework

I have a bot with a Facebook Channel. I pass the following to Facebook Graph API:

```
string url = $"{PSID}?fields=first_name,last_name,email&access_token{accessToken}";
```

I can get the user's name, but I get an empty string for the email. Since it's a chat bot, I couldn't understand if there is a way to set up permissions etc. But from what I've read, I don't need special permission to get email.

I am testing with my own facebook account added in Test Roles, not using a test user. I have 1 of 4 emails set to public in my Contact Information/Email.

Comment: _"But from what I've read, I don't need special permission to get email."_ - I'd be interested to know where exactly you read that then, could you link to the exact position in the documentation?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/ `Basic permissions, (public_profile, user_friends, and email)...` did I misunderstand that?

Comment: You are confusing asking users of your app to grant a permission, with review of your app's use of permissions by Facebook. Those basic permissions do not need review, but you still need to ask your app users to grant them to your app to get access to the data they guard.